# Rounding UITableView Image Corners

Tags: iphone, uitableview, quartz-graphics

I need to add rounded corners to an image in a UITable View cell to 3px. What's the best way to go about this? Apparently you can use the quartz framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get rounded corners is Core Animation:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
```

Comment: I get an error "Request for member Layer is something not a structure or union". Any ideas?

Comment: You need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and add the QuartzCore.framework to your target.

Comment: I've already done that - still no good though. Any other ideas? Thanks btw.

Comment: Well, if you really wrote "Layer" with a capital L it's no wonder you get an error message.

Comment: No, I wrote it as image.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f; To add the framework I right clicked the Frameworks folder, selected "Add Existing Framework" and chose the Quartz Framework. I then added the #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> to the header of the table view.

Comment: So what is `image`? You need to apply this to a `UIImageView`, not a `UIImage`.

Comment: image is a UIImage so um what's the best way for a UIImage to get rounded corners then I guess?

Comment: Try:   CALayer * layer = imageView.layer;
  layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;